# What's the equation behind the 4x4 transformation matrix used in CSS3 / SVG?

Tags: css, matrix, svg, 3d, transform

Both [SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG-Transforms/#threed-matrix-definition) and [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-3d-transforms/#funcdef-matrix3d) specs talk about 4x4 matrixes for transformations in many ways.

But I can't find a comprehensive base-formula, such as [this 3x3 formula for SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#EstablishingANewUserSpace):

[image: 3x3 Transformation Matrix formula according to SVG spec]

Are there any resources on this or is it not that simple with a 4x4 matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the specification... it looks like it's just:

```
|-- --|       |--       --|      |-- --|
|  x  |       |  a b c d  |      |  x  |
|  y  |  ---  |  e f g h  |  \/  |  y  |
|  z  |  ---  |  i j k l  |  /\  |  z  |
|  1  |       |  0 0 0 1  |      |  1  |
|-- --|       |--       --|      |-- --|
```

Which would make sense, since it's just an extended version of the 2D version.